# Kali linux 2.0 Not showing wireless networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I know this question has been asked but not in this manner.I have throughly searched and could not find anything close to my problem.

I am currently running kali 2.0 alone on my macbook pro retina 2012. When i first booted into the live version i was able to find networks. After the install though its a different story. What makes this different. Is when i check ifconfig my wlan0 shows up.
  Not to mention iwconfig shows me connected to my home network. Which wont work unless i start a service called smbd after i start that service im good to go. I just still cant see any networks.

I would also like to add that i did encrypt the whole drive which had a few of its own problems but is working now. Also when i boot in kali it says waiting for LSB service to start and bringing up interfaces. It will hang there for more than a min and a half before it starts. I wonder if that has something to do with it. Well Thank you in advance for any help that is given I appreciate these communities. Thank you.